# Concerning local development in two variables

Tags: complex-analysis

- In one complex variable, a meromorphic function $f$ with a simple pole at $s=s_0$ can be written in the form
  $$f(s) = \frac{A}{s-s_0} + H(s),$$

where $A$ is a constant (the residue at $s=s_0$) and $H$ is an analytic function around $s_0$.

- In two (or more) complex variables, the situation lacks of symmetry. I read that a meromorphic function around $(1/2,1)$ with polar lines (for instance) $w+3s-5/2$ and $w-1$ (that is to say, $(w-1)(w+3s-5/2)f(s, w)$ is analytic around $(1/2,1)$) can be written in the form
  $$f(s, w) = \frac{A}{(w-1)(s-1/2)} + \frac{B(s)}{w-1} + \frac{C}{(w-1)(w+s-5/2)} + \frac{D(s)}{w+3s-5/2} + H(s, w),$$

where $H$ is holomorphic around $(1/2,1)$.

I have an issue understanding why this is true. Why are some "residues" depending on $s$ and other not? Is this the only form or can we also write something with residues depending only on $w$?

Why couldn't I take $B(s) = \lim_{w=1} (w-1)f(s, w)$ and write
$$f(s, w) = \frac{B(s)}{w-1} + M(s, w)$$

where $M(s, w)$ is holomorphic around $w=1$?